# Let checkbox be checked with delay

Tags: javascript, checkbox, delay

I have a simple question: How can you let a checkbox be checked automatically (as already shown in the code snippet), but with a delay of 100ms, so that when you load the page after 100ms, the checkbox gets checked (and will stay checked)? I think you need to use JavaScript for it, but I don't know how to use it.

```html
<input checked type="checkbox"/>
```

Any ideas for a clean and good way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) to count to 100ms. Then grab the checkbox with its `id` then use `.checked = true`.

```js
setTimeout(function(){
document.getElementById('chech').checked = true;
},1000) // used 1 second to show the effect
```

```html
<input id="chech" type="checkbox"/>
```

**OR**

```js
setTimeout(function(){
document.getElementById('chech').click(); 
},1000)
```

```html
<input id="chech" type="checkbox"/>
```

Comment: Thank you. I got one question remaining, do you know how to use this script with this code, which already has  a name and id added to it? :
https://jsfiddle.net/3cfrsv0x/

Comment: @DanielBoven just change the id to p4

Answer (score 1):

```html
<input id='myInput' type="checkbox"/>
<script>
window.onload = () => { 
  setTimeout(() => {
    document.getElementById("myInput").setAttribute("checked", true);
  }, 100);
}
</script>
```